# Web table is not being completely fetched by VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, web-scraping

I need to fetch the price table from [this site](http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html).

For this I have already developed some code:

```
Sub TableExample()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim strURL As String

    strURL = "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html"

    ' replace with URL of your choice

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
         '.Visible = True

        .navigate strURL
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
                Set doc = IE.document
                GetAllTables doc

                .Quit
            End With
        End Sub

       Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

     ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim I As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
        'rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        If tabno = 5 Then

        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            colno = 6
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                If colno = 5 And nextrow < 1 Then
                    Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("shop")
                    Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 2).getElementsByTagName("img").getElementsByClassName("btn-goto-shop")
                    rng.Value = imgTgt(0).getAttribute("alt")

                Else
                    rng.Value = cl.innerText
                End If
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                I = I + 1
                colno = colno + 1
            Next cl
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
            I = 0
        Next rw
        End If
    Next tbl

    ws.Cells.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

Through this code I can get the desired result, except that the last column with the shop name given is not being fetched. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the HTML for the page you can see that the elements with className `productOffers-listItemOfferPrice` have the required info. There is more information than perhaps you might realise. See my code output at bottom.

[image: Example from HTML]

---

In the main sub `GetTable`, I use an XHR request to get the page HTML and store it in an HTML document.

When you do `.getElementsByClassName("productOffers-listItemOfferPrice")` to get all the item info, you need to parse each elements `.outerHTML`.

---

The helper function  `GetTransactionInfo` uses split function to get just the product info part of the `.outerHTML`. The returned string looks like the following example sample:

```
"&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;"product_id": &#9;&#9;&#9;"143513",&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;"product_name": ..."
```

---

The helper function `TidyString` takes an inputString and regex pattern, applies regex pattern matching to tidy the product information string, by matching unwanted strings and replacing them with empty literal strings (`vbNullString`).

---

**Regex pattern 1:**

For example, the first regex pattern `"&#\d+;"` gets rid of all the &# with numbers in the string:

[image: Regex1] <sub>[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/lgzufM/1)</sub>

---

**Regex pattern 2:**

The second regex pattern, `Chr$(34) & headers(currentItem) & Chr$(34) & ":"`, removes the product header information from the string i.e. to get just the values.

E.g. it takes `"product_id": "143513"` and returns `"143513"`.

[image: Regex2] <sub>[Try it](http://%20https://regex101.com/r/lgzufM/2)</sub>

---

**Example page info (sample)**

[image: Sample page view]

---

**Example code output:**

[image: Sample output]

---

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit

'Tools > References > HTML Object Library
Public Sub GetTable()

    Dim sResponse As String, listItems As Object, html As HTMLDocument, headers()
    headers = Array("product_id", "product_name", "product_price", "product_category", "currency", "spr", "shop_name", "delivery_time", "shop_rating", "position", "free_return", "approved_shipping")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set listItems = .getElementsByClassName("productOffers-listItemOfferPrice")
    End With

    Dim currentItem As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For currentItem = 0 To listItems.Length - 1
            Dim tempString As String, columnValues() As String
            tempString = TidyString(GetTransactionInfo(listItems(currentItem).outerHTML), "&#\d+;")
            columnValues = GetColumnValues(tempString, headers)
            .Cells(currentItem + 2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(columnValues) + 1) = columnValues
        Next currentItem
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetTransactionInfo(ByVal inputString) As String
    'Split to get just the transaction items i.e. Headers and associated values
    GetTransactionInfo = Split(Split(inputString, """transaction"",")(1), "}")(0)
End Function

Public Function TidyString(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal matchPattern As String) As String
    'Extract transaction info
    'Use regex to find these unwanted strings and replace pattern e.g. &#\d+;
    'Example inputString

    Dim regex As Object, tempString As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = matchPattern
    End With

    If regex.TEST(inputString) Then
        TidyString = regex.Replace(inputString, vbNullString)
    Else
        TidyString = inputString
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetColumnValues(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal headers As Variant) As Variant
    ' Example input string "product_id": "143513","product_name": "Canon 500D Nahlinse 72mm","product_price": "128.0","product_category": "26570","currency": "EUR","spr": "cfd","shop_name": "computeruniverse.net","delivery_time": "long","shop_rating": "100","position": "1","free_return": "14","approved_shipping": "false"
    ' Extract just the inner string value of each header e.g. 143513
    Dim arr() As String, currentItem As Long, tempString As String
    tempString = inputString
    For currentItem = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        tempString = TidyString(tempString, Chr$(34) & headers(currentItem) & Chr$(34) & ":")
    Next currentItem
    arr = Split(Replace$(tempString, Chr$(34), vbNullString), ",")
    GetColumnValues = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the modified code that I'm running

```
Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

 ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As Object
Dim rw As Object
Dim cl As Object
Dim tabno As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim I As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    tabno = tabno + 1
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & nextrow)
    'rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
    If tabno = 5 Then

For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        colno = 1
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            If colno = 5 Then
                rng.Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("shop")(nextrow - 6).getElementsByTagName("img")(1).getAttribute("alt")
            Else
                rng.Value = cl.innerText
            End If
            Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
            I = I + 1
            colno = colno + 1
        Next cl
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
        I = 0
    Next rw
    End If
Next tbl

ws.Cells.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks ron for the reply but after changing "if colno = 5 And nextrow < 1" and replacing rng.Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("shop")(nextrow - 6).getElementsByTagName("img")(1).getAttribute("alt") does not give me the alt text of img tag...where am i missing the point?

Comment: "And nextrow < 1" also needs to be changed - this condition is also never met by the time you get to the data you're after in row(2).  Did you mean to write "And nextrow > 1"?

Comment: do you even need the "And" part of the statement?

Comment: OK, so you probably want to change it to "And nextrow > 1"

Comment: with "If colno = 5 And nextrow < 1 Then"  I am getting everything except img alt tag.

Comment: hmmm, are you using my rng.Value expression or the one in your original code?  When I run without "And nextrow < 1" and use my rng.Value expression I get everything

Comment: Am using your rng.Value only...please check this following piece of code  colno = 5
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                If colno = 5 Then
                  rng.Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("shop")(nextrow - 6).getElementsByTagName("img")(1).getAttribute("alt")
                Else
                    rng.Value = cl.innerText
                End If
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                I = I + 1
                colno = colno + 1
            Next cl

Comment: After "For Each rw In tbl.Rows", change "colno = 5" to "colno = 1"

Comment: did it but still no luck...is that code running up at your end...can you please share me the full code

Comment: OK, I posted the code I'm running in the answer block

Comment: Finally I have figured out the issue and its here only...    If colno = 5 And nextrow > 5 Then   the nextrow has incremented by 5 so i have to check whether it is >5 or not...