# Web table not fetching the correct data by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

With the followoing code I can fetch the price table from this webpage http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html

But from another page [here](http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/1866742_-335-billingham.html)  this table is not being fetched...though these two pages are identical. I can't figure out where am lacking.

Any help on this is deeply appreciable.

```
Sub TableExample()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim strURL As String

    strURL = "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html"


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .navigate strURL
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Set doc = IE.document
        GetAllTables doc

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub

Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        If tabno = 5 Then
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            colno = 5

            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                If colno = 5 And nextrow > 5 Then
                    Set classColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("shop")
                    Set imgTgt = classColl(nextrow - 6).getElementsByTagName("img")
                    rng.Value = imgTgt(0).getAttribute("alt")
                Else
                    rng.Value = cl.innerText
                End If
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                i = i + 1
                colno = colno + 1
            Next cl
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -i)
            i = 0
        Next rw
        End If

    Next tbl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table numbers change between the two urls.  Table 5 is the table you're interested in for the first url, but Table 6 is the one of interest in the 2nd url.  However both tables of interest have the same id ("offers-list"), so instead of looking for the fifth table, adjust your code to look for the Table with the ID "offers-list"

change

```
  If tabno = 5 Then
```

to

```
  If InStr(1, tbl.outerhtml, "Produktbezeichnung des Shops", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

This will get you close.  There are other changes on the second web page that your current code isn't quite handling - but like I said this will get you close.

Comment: thanks Ron! you are right...I just change the tabno to 6 and it works! but any idea how to find with table id

Comment: or can you help me to find the table no of "offers-list" in the page?

Comment: i have tried it but with no luck...how can i find the table no of "offers-list"? I think if we can figure it out  then this prob will be solved

Comment: doc.getelementbyid("offers-list").innerhtml or .innertext will get the info from that table, but I think it would be a bigger rework for your code than the change I noted above.  When I used the above substitution it worked the sane as your "if tabno = 5" or "if tabno = 6"

Comment: Hi, what if the table has no ID it has a class though..then how to fetch that table?\

Comment: this is a different question, if I answered your initial question please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `If tabno = 5 Then` with

```
For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
       ' tabno = tabno + 1
       If tbl.className = "orangebox_rowborder" Then
```

Thanks @Ron for guiding me for this...thanks a ton Dude

Answer (score 0):

The following works for each URL so is more robust and is a lot faster than the method you are currently using as it does away with the IE browser nvaigation.

For a lengthy code explanation please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983633/6241235).

```
Option Explicit

'Tools > References > HTML Object Library
Public Sub GetTable()
    Const URL = "https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/1866742_-335-billingham.html" '<==Change this
    Dim sResponse As String, listItems As Object, html As HTMLDocument, headers()
    headers = Array("product_id", "product_name", "product_price", "product_category", "currency", "spr", "shop_name", "delivery_time", "shop_rating", "position", "free_return", "approved_shipping")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set listItems = .getElementsByClassName("productOffers-listItemOfferPrice")
    End With

    Dim currentItem As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For currentItem = 0 To listItems.Length - 1
            Dim tempString As String, columnValues() As String
            tempString = TidyString(GetTransactionInfo(listItems(currentItem).outerHTML), "&#\d+;")
            columnValues = GetColumnValues(tempString, headers)
            .Cells(currentItem + 2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(columnValues) + 1) = columnValues
        Next currentItem
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetTransactionInfo(ByVal inputString) As String
    'Split to get just the transaction items i.e. Headers and associated values
    GetTransactionInfo = Split(Split(inputString, """transaction"",")(1), "}")(0)
End Function

Public Function TidyString(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal matchPattern As String) As String
    'Extract transaction info
    'Use regex to find these unwanted strings and replace pattern e.g. &#\d+;
    'Example inputString

    Dim regex As Object, tempString As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = matchPattern
    End With

    If regex.test(inputString) Then
        TidyString = regex.Replace(inputString, vbNullString)
    Else
        TidyString = inputString
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetColumnValues(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal headers As Variant) As Variant
    ' Example input string "product_id": "143513","product_name": "Canon 500D Nahlinse 72mm","product_price": "128.0","product_category": "26570","currency": "EUR","spr": "cfd","shop_name": "computeruniverse.net","delivery_time": "long","shop_rating": "100","position": "1","free_return": "14","approved_shipping": "false"
    ' Extract just the inner string value of each header e.g. 143513
    Dim arr() As String, currentItem As Long, tempString As String
    tempString = inputString
    For currentItem = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        tempString = TidyString(tempString, Chr$(34) & headers(currentItem) & Chr$(34) & ":")
    Next currentItem
    arr = Split(Replace$(tempString, Chr$(34), vbNullString), ",")
    GetColumnValues = arr
End Function
```